# Salesforce Lightning Experience

Tags: developer-console, lightning-experience

I have a few questions about Salesforce Lightning Experience. 
[image]

I want to have a look at it on my dev console and play around with it instead of using the salesforce classic. I'm not the one to decide if our company is going to use the salesforce Lightning experience since there is a 100 of people using our salesforce. We have 2 organizations Production and Dev. As a developer im using dev. 
i wanna know if i can only install Lightning experience for 1 user (myself), will everything from  salesroom classic automatically integrate with the Lightning experience does any data get lost modified ? and most important of all Is it worth it ?? 
 
Looking for people who have used it and have positive/negative expereicne with it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You cannot enable it for one user but you can enable/disable it for one/multiple profiles. Probably, permission set would help you but I haven't tried it.

In **Administrative Permissions** section on profile, you can control this behavior. See image below:

[image]

You can create one new profile and assign it to only one user. This would solve the purpose.

**Data Loss:**
No, your data will not be touched either you switch to Lightning or switch back to classic.

Go through following post for high level overview of lightning: [Review: Meet the New Salesforce Lightning Experience!](https://www.google.co.in/url?sa=t&rct=j&q=&esrc=s&source=web&cd=1&cad=rja&uact=8&ved=0ahUKEwjU3MWqjeXJAhWkIKYKHU_NAfsQFggbMAA&url=https%3A%2F%2Fwww.linkedin.com%2Fpulse%2Freview-meet-new-salesforce-lightning-experience-struck-ashwani-soni&usg=AFQjCNHlSpicTCEHNMWoWJDa_iUksqEfIQ&sig2=y8GgwrJ2HtA9lgdURenbgg&bvm=bv.110151844,d.dGY). For deeper understanding complete [Salesforce Trailhead challenges](https://www.google.co.in/url?sa=t&rct=j&q=&esrc=s&source=web&cd=1&cad=rja&uact=8&ved=0ahUKEwjYx5eLjeXJAhXH46YKHY63AqMQFggcMAA&url=https%3A%2F%2Fdeveloper.salesforce.com%2Ftrailhead%2Fmodule%2Flightning_components&usg=AFQjCNHhXqHhD5sSYT0uLpsrKBV0p8VIkg&sig2=gBmbRDBFhQmU9NPPs1fRFg) for Lightning experience.

For developer the experience is not very helpful. Experience is helpful for end user specially, for sales and service use cases.